# Missing color in tmux terminal with plugins

Tags: linux, plugins, tmux

The terminal color doesn't change after Tmux plugins. I heard Vim has a similar problem, I also don't see color in it.
I checked the variables in echo `$TERM`:

- in openSUSE - `xterm-256color`
- in Tmux - `screen-256color`

To solve this problem, I added to ~/.tmux.conf, but it did not help

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"
set -ga terminal-overrides '*:Ss=\E[%p1%d q:Se=\E[ q'
set-environment -g COLORTERM "truecolor"
set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"

set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"

set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",256col:Tc"
```

More info: I mean, after installing the Tmux plugin, the main area of the terminal remained the default. Only the bottom line has changed. I have attached a screenshot:[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "Terminal color doesn't change"?

Comment: I mean, after installing the tmux plugin, the main area of the terminal remained default. Only the bottom line has changed. I have attached a screenshot and will add this to my main question